# How to instantiate contract instances with ethers.js and alchemy-sdk

Tags: contract-development, ethers.js, alchemy

(Found this from the public Alchemy discord, and wanted to ask the question here so it can get indexed online )

---

I'm trying to instantiate contracts in my javascript code so that I can call ABI methods.

However, when I try to use the `alchemy-sdk` object to create a `new Contract`, I get an error.

This is how I'm setting it up:

```js
const CompoundorContract = new ethers.Contract(
  CONSTANTS.ADDRESSES.COMPOUNDER_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
  CONSTANTS.CONTRACTS.COMPOUNDOR_ABI,
  alchemy.core
);
```

and this is the error I get:

```js
Error: invalid signer or provider (argument="signerOrProvider", value={"config":{"apiKey":"my_key","network":"opt-mainnet","maxRetries":5}},code=INVALID_ARGUMENT,version=contracts/5.6.2
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this [example of using the alchemy-sdk to connect to eth mainnet to load a contract instance](https://github.com/alchemyplatform/Alchemy-Hacker-Handbook/blob/main/evm_snippets/LoadContract/load-contract.js).

I think the key difference is that you should use `await alchemy.config.getProvider()` instead of what you're currently doing with `alchemy.core`

This is because you need to instantiate one instance of an Alchemy provider connection vs. using the namespaced sdk module `alchemy.core`

Answer (score 2):

instead of passing `alchemy.core`, pass return value of this

```
const ethersProvider = await alchemy.config.getProvider()
```

final:

```
const CompoundorContract = new 

ethers.Contract(
  CONSTANTS.ADDRESSES.COMPOUNDER_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
  CONSTANTS.CONTRACTS.COMPOUNDOR_ABI,
  ethersProvider
);
```

please leave a comment if it does not work.

vote up plz, if it works:)

Comment: This works, should be accepted.